# SQL query to display records in various scenarios

Tags: sql

I have a form which displays data from my table. The form has a field for account id and start date and end date. I want to have multiple scenarios being displayed and have explained them below.

1. If ONLY the account id is selected, then all the rows pertaining to that account id should be displayed.
2. If ONLY the start and end dates are selected, then all the rows within that range should be displayed.
3. If all 3 fields(account id, start and end date) are selected, then the display the particular account ids within the specified date range.
4. If none of the fields are selected, then display the whole table.

I am able to figure out scenarios 1 and 2 but just can't get 3 & 4 to work. Below is my query I have used:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_call_log_detail WHERE dealer_id = '$call_id' OR time_stamp <= '$endDate' AND time_stamp >= '$startDate' ORDER BY id ASC
```

I even tried putting parenthesis in the OR clause but that does nothing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that if not selected, then its value is an empty string.

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl_call_log_detail 
    WHERE
     (dealer_id = '$call_id' AND '$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND '$startDate' ='1970-01-01')
  OR ( time_stamp <= '$endDate' AND time_stamp >= '$startDate'  
                    AND (dealer_id = '$call_id' OR'$call_id'='' ))    
  OR ('$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND '$startDate' ='1970-01-01'  AND '$call_id'='')
     ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: This takes care of scenario 2 and 3. 1 and 4 aren't working now

Comment: Show me the values when not selected '$endDate', '$startDate' and '$call_id'

Comment: Its an html table so the table doesn't populate when only the account id is selected or none of the fields are selected

Comment: Print the SQL query in each case please, or at least show your code.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_call_log_detail WHERE (dealer_id = '' AND '1970-01-01'='' AND '1970-01-01' ='') OR ( time_stamp <= '1970-01-01' AND time_stamp >= '1970-01-01' AND (dealer_id = '' OR''='' )) OR ('1970-01-01'='' AND '1970-01-01' ='' AND ''='') ORDER BY id ASC.

When nothing is selected, this is the query getting printed

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_call_log_detail WHERE (dealer_id = '87' AND '1970-01-01'='' AND '1970-01-01' ='') OR ( time_stamp <= '1970-01-01' AND time_stamp >= '1970-01-01' AND (dealer_id = '87' OR'87'='' )) OR ('1970-01-01'='' AND '1970-01-01' ='' AND '87'='') ORDER BY id ASC.     When only dealer id is selected, this gets printed

Comment: Do you want the query of the other 2 cases as well? Those work with your answer but I can show it to you if you'd like

Comment: Make sure you understand the logic or ask me. Glad it helps.