# Can we display table records in multiple pages using POST?

Tags: php, post, get

I have a form that uses the method post. The form contains a submit button and on clicking it, my database records get displayed in an html table. I would like to limit the number of rows (5) displayed to each page, but I'm not looking to use GET. Is there any way I can do that with my post method?

```
// My form using post method
<form action = "" name = "dealer_call_log.php" id = "dealer_call_log.php" method = "post">


//Data displayed in the table below from post

 $record_per_page = 5;
$page = '';
 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
     $page = $_GET['page'];
 }
 else{
     $page = 1;
 }

 $start_from = ($page - 1) * $record_per_page;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo '<center>';

    echo '<br>';

    $sql = "SELECT SFID, Comment, Time FROM tbl_call_log_detail 
    WHERE
     (dealer_id = '$call_id' AND '$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND '$startDate' ='1970-01-01')
  OR ( Time <= '$endDate' AND Time >= '$startDate'  
                    AND (dealer_id = '$call_id' OR'$call_id'='' ))    
  OR ('$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND '$startDate' ='1970-01-01'  AND '$call_id'='')
     ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT $start_from, $record_per_page" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $all_property = array();
    echo "<table class = 'data-table' border = '1' cellpadding = '9' bgcolor = '#CCCCCC'>
            <tr class = 'data-heading'>";
    while($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)){
        echo '<td><b> '. $property ->name. ' </b></td>';
        array_push($all_property, $property ->name);

    }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($all_property as $item){
            echo '<td> '. $row[$item] . ' </td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</center>';
            }
        }
$page_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_call_log_detail ";
$page_result = mysqli_query($conn, $page_query);
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records/$record_per_page);
$start_loop = $page;
$difference = $total_pages - $page;

if($difference <= $total_pages){
    $start_loop = $total_pages - $difference;
}
$end_loop = $start_loop + 2;
if($difference > $total_pages){
    $end_loop = $total_pages;
}
if($page > 1){
    echo "<a href= 'dealer_call_log.php?page=1'>First</a>";
    echo "<a href= 'dealer_call_log.php?page=".($page - 1)."'><<</a>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++){
    echo "<a href= 'dealer_call_log.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
}
if($page <= $end_loop){
    echo "<a href= 'dealer_call_log.php?page=".($page + 1)."'>>></a>";
    echo "<a href= 'dealer_call_log.php?page=".$total_pages."'>Last</a>";
}
 if($page < 1){
$page = 1;
 }
    echo '</table>';
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I would like to limit the number of rows displayed to 20 on each page, but I'm not looking to use GET." These two things are not related. You can send data by whichever HTTP method you feel is most appropriate. Lots of examples of paging, and even pre-built plugins to help you, if you google around.

Comment: BTW, your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL, as it appears you may be doing.

Comment: Please please please look into using prepared statements - allowing user-set variables to appear in your queries leaves you vulnerable to injection attacks. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php has some examples to help you get started with prepared statements and how to bind parameters to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0` to get the first 20 results. Then for the next page you can use `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20` the get the second set of 20 results. See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) for more information on this

You can also keep track of your pagenumber with post but you'll have to post it in an input field. You can use an input type hidden like so: `<input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0">` and change the value everytime you switch page.

Then you could do something like this:

```
    $limit = 20;
    if(isset($_POST['pageNumber']) {
        $page = $_POST['pageNumber'];
    } else {
        $page = 0;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT sfid, comment, time_stamp, time_of_submission FROM tbl_call_log_detail 
    WHERE
     (dealer_id = '$call_id' AND '$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND '$startDate' ='1970-01-01')
  OR ( time_stamp <= '$endDate' AND time_stamp >= '$startDate'  
                    AND (dealer_id = '$call_id' OR'$call_id'='' ))    
  OR ('$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND '$startDate' ='1970-01-01'  AND '$call_id'='')
     ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
  LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET " . $page * $limit;

echo '<input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="' . $page + 1 . '">'
```

Comment: This doesn't have page links so its still showing all the results in 1 page

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it has page links. When you go through this code the first time it will give you the first 20 results (because of the `LIMIT 20`) and the second time you should have `pageNumber` set. Then the offset will change to 20, and you should get the next 20 results.

Comment: The page now shows the 20 results in the same page. At the bottom, it displays " 1 >" from the value attribute of the hidden input. There's no where to go to the next page

Comment: Just updated my code. I still don't see any data when I click on page 2 or 3 or any other page. I really appreciate you being so patient with me

Comment: This is because you check if `$_POST['submit']` is set, but it isn't set anymore because you haven't clicked on a submit button this time.

Comment: I edited it again. This time when I click on a page link(let's say 3) the url changes to ?page=3 but nothing gets displayed. If I click the submit button again, it shows the correct data. How should I fix it so that it shows the correct set of rows right when I click the page link

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` <- this is why that's happening. It'll only show data when you posted your submit button. When you click on a page link it will reload your page so your submit button will no longer be posted. You should either check on something else that IS set or just remove that check alltogether

Comment: But my pagination links are outside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {..}. So why would it still affect the pagination?

Comment: Because you calculate your totalpages based on your data and it will skip the whole data part if `$_POST['submit']` isn't set.

First time you get on your site. You click the submit button -> the submit button gets posted to your page and it will show data.

Next you click a pagelink, nothing will be posted because you're not clicking a submit button. It will navigate to your page again, only this time with a pagenumber in the URL. But because nothing is posted it'll skip everything that's inside of the  `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` because the submit button wasn't posted this time

Comment: I'm not sure where you set `$callid`, `$startdate` and `$enddate` but if this isn't based on anything in your form you could just remove the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` or change it to something like this `if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_GET['page'])){`

Comment: Ohh okay I get it now. But the problem is I need the submit button to display the relevant data. So what should I check to be set if not the submit button that will display the relevant rows right on the click of the page link?

Comment: I set $call_id by checking if the submit button gets posted, running an sql query if it does and passing the relevant row on that variable. $startDate and $endDate are just date functions parsed with strtotime

Comment: Besides `['submit']` is there anything else in your `$_POST`?

Comment: So after using your last comment, my records get displayed right when I click the link. But the WHERE clause in sql is failing. Here is how I got that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351304/sql-query-to-display-records-in-various-scenarios

And no, I just have the submit button for the records and html table, which are both in the code above

Comment: No errors, but when I choose just the start and end date, nothing gets displayed. When I choose just the dealer id, the whole database gets displayed and not just of the id I selected. When I choose all 3(dealer id, start and end date) again nothing gets displayed

Comment: Alright so now I understand that your data is based on your form. 

My answer will probably not work then. 

Things you could do are:

1. put the call_id, startdate and enddate, in the url and get them from your `$_GET` 

2. use ajax to get your data and make a new call everytime you click one of your buttons

3. put the call_id, startdate and enddate in hidden inputs and let the anchor tags submit your form when you click them using javascript (something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906066/making-href-anchor-tag-request-post-instead-of-get)

Comment: How do I do your 1st option. I kinda wanna stay away from ajax and javascript and would like to stick with php. how do I get the call_id, start and end date in the url?

Comment: in your form make `method="get"` instead of post

Comment: That doesn't work because now in my url, the call_id is blank

Comment: I was looking at your 3rd option as well but that wouldn't work because I cannot have startdate and enddate as hidden since the user might want to provide a date range. The call_id is already hidden though

Comment: You could also keep them visible, tho the user then would be able to change it halfway through and you could get some OFFSET out of range exception. But aslong as they're in your form it would work

Comment: I've been trying this for a couple of days now but none of the options are working. I've never used ajax before so there's that. With GET, the url displays the name and start and end date, but it doesn't display the data. Not sure how to use javascript here as well, so yeah I'm very lost in this situation. Please help!