# Displaying records with pagination using different criteria in the form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pagination

I've been searching for this for a long time but haven't been able to get anything. I have form a which has a drop down to display the names, start and end dates. I want to paginate the data using names, start and end dates, meaning if you select a name(ABC), then all the X records for that name should be paginated with Y records per page. my pagination works, but how can I get it to work within those criteria? If I go to a different page, then it just goes back to showing all the data, though it still remains Y per page.

```
    if(isset($_GET['submit']) || isset($_GET['page'])){ 
    echo '<center>';
    echo '<br>';
    $sql = "SELECT SFID, Comment, Time 
            FROM tbl_call_log_detail 
            WHERE
            ( dealer_id = '$call_id' AND 
              '$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND 
              '$startDate' ='1970-01-01'
            )
            OR 
            ( Time <= '$endDate' AND 
              Time >= '$startDate' AND 
              ( dealer_id = '$call_id' OR '$call_id'='' )
            )    
            OR 
            ( '$endDate'='1970-01-01' AND 
              '$startDate' ='1970-01-01' AND 
              '$call_id'=''
            )
            ORDER BY Time DESC 
            LIMIT $start_from, $record_per_page ";
```

I think my select query has an issue somewhere but I can put up other parts of my code too if needed. Here is what I got the last time I asked but I'm still stuck: [Can we display table records in multiple pages using POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409070/can-we-display-table-records-in-multiple-pages-using-post)

**EDIT:**

This is how I'm assigning the post and get variables:

```
$edate = '';
$sdate = '';
$urlparameter = '';
$call_id = '';
if(isset($_GET['account_name'])){
    $account_name = $_GET['account_name'];
    $urlparameter = "&account_name=".$account_name;
}
if(isset($_GET['edate'])){
    $edate = $_GET['edate'];
    $urlparameter .= "&edate=".$edate;
}
if(isset($_GET['sdate'])){
    $sdate = $_GET['sdate'];
    $urlparameter .= "&sdate=".$sdate;
}
 $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate));
 $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate));

// Displaying the relevant data on the page
$record_per_page = 5;
 $page = '';
 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
     $page = intval($_GET['page']);
 }
 else{
     $page = 1;
 }
 $start_from = ($page - 1) * $record_per_page;...
```

**HTML FORM**:

```
<form action = "" name = "dealer_call_log" id = "myform" method = "get">
<input type = "submit" name = "logout" id = "logout" value = "Log Out" />
Name of the dealer:<br>
<?php
//Displaying the names of all the dealers in the database 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dealer_info ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY account_name ASC ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<select name = 'account_name' id = 'idaname' >"; 
echo "<option value = ''>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value = '" . $row['account_name'] . "'>" . $row['account_name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<br><br>
Select start date:<br>
<input type = "date" name = "sdate" id = "sdate" value = ""/>
<div align = "center">
Select end date:<br>
<input type = "date" name = "edate" id = "edate" value = ""/><br><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Submit"  />
```

After this is my first set of codes

```
(if(isset($_GET['submit']) || isset($_GET['page'])){ ...
</form>
```

Comment: Before you tackle pagination, you need to understand what variables need to be passed to the script, and how.  First off, why `POST`?  As a general rule, `GET` is more suited to searches and pagination, because it doesn't mess up the back button.  It also means you wouldn't have to keep straight two different ways the script receives its variables.  If you are expecting any `POST` variables to use in the query (and your example doesn't show where the variables are coming from), then when somebody hits the next page link, you won't have all the necessary variables.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how your script is collecting the information it needs.  (i.e., where are you assigning `$_POST` and /or `$_GET` variables.

Comment: @TimMorton I edited the code above

Comment: hey, you taught me something :)  I didn't know PHP had a null coalesce operator. Cool.  OK, one more request:  what does the HTML look like that allows someone to request the next page? What I'm trying to find out is if all the variables are getting to your script or not.

Comment: FYI, as an addendum to my first comment-- another reason `POST` is not the preferred method for this is based on REST verbs.  You typically have four basic operations: create, read, update, and delete.  (CRUD) The http verbs that correspond are `post`, `get`, `patch`, and `delete`.  Since browsers only implement `post` and `get`, `get` is used for **reading** and `post` is used for anything that would **alter** data. So using `GET` in your case would be the best practice. (using `post` will make you end up fighting your interface)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by the HTML code allowing to request the next page, because that's done by pagination, but I put up some HTML. If that's not what you mean, then I can show the relevant stuff as well when I know what it is. Also, never really thought I could teach someone something about programming, but I guess miracles happen hehe!.. P.s the reason I want post is because I have a submit button which will shows the data matching the name and date range. I tried changing my form method to get, but it doesn't work at all

Comment: Just made some edits and it all works now. You were right @TimMorton to use GET so thanks for recommending that!

Comment: Congrats ;)  I was looking for the html that sends `$page` to the script, to see if the `POST` data was being sent at the same time. Sounds like you got it, though, so happy coding!